# How to get date of the latest 2 created files in a folder?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm pretty new to Python, just learning it step by step, in this particular case I'm trying to create a code where I need these 2 file dates of a said folder, to later compare them to another specific date. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply, list files in directory, get the os.path.getmtime this gives you time to epoch. Convert that to date using fromtimestamp.
Code: 
[{"time":  datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp( os.path.getmtime(filename)), "file": filename} for filename in os.listdir()]